# Like Button Showing Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a like button, this is what i did so far,

```
$(".click-like").click(function(){
  var curr_elem = $(this) ;
  $.get($(this).attr('href-like'), function(data){
    var my_div = $(data).find(".click-like");
    $(curr_elem).html(my_div);
  });
  return false; // prevent loading URL from href
});
```

Here is the html. This is generated in a 'for' loop, looping through multiple data

```html
<a class="click-like" href-like="URL">{% if request.user in answer.likes.all %}Liked{% else %}Like{% endif %}</a>
```

Since I have this like button inside For loop looping though multiple Games, so it's being appeared below every game. When I click `Like` it returns Like or Liked button equal number of times as number of Games.

How can we prevent that from happening? Thank You . . .

Comment: Your code seems fine - it's all related to the clicked `a` element through the use of the `this` keyword. Could you show a (simplified) example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sir, if I add `.html()` after .find(.click-like) method it's working fine for First button but not for others. Why so?

Comment: @KumarShivam `html` returns the html content of first matched element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be this line

```
var my_div = $(data).find(".click-like"); //you are finding all the .click-like instead of the one you clicked
$(curr_elem).html(my_div);
```

Replace this with

```
$(".click-like").click(function(){
  var curr_elem = $(this) ;
  var hrefLike = curr_elem.attr('href-like')
  $.get( hrefLike , function(data){
    var my_div = $( data ).find( ".click-like[href-like='" + hrefLike + "']"); //only get the specific one with url
    $( curr_elem ).html( my_div );
  });
  return false; // prevent loading URL from href
});
```

Comment: OMG! I was hanged with this code for like 1 month. Thank You very much Sir :) It's working perfectly fine :)